# C++ vector initialize with value

Tags: c++, initialization

As a C++ beginner, I know that we can initialize a vector of vectors using:

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> vec(10, vector<int>(15, 0));
```

which is quite efficient,
but when I want to do the same thing with a struct I wrote, The code won't compile:

```cpp
vector<TreeNode> vec(10, TreeNode("abc"));
```

the struct looks like this:

```cpp
struct TreeNode {
    std::string val;
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;
    explicit TreeNode(std::string& val) {
        this->val = val;
        left = nullptr, right = nullptr;
    }

};
```

I am wondering what's the problem here

I used Clion as my IDE, IDE was reporting this error:
`No matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'const char [4]' to 'TreeNode'`

And compiler was reporting this error:
[image]

Comment: If you say it won't compile, you need to provide the compiler errors.

Comment: Just an assumption, use `const std::string &val` as the parameter to the constructor.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `vector`. Just plain `TreeNode("abc");` already fails to compile.

Comment: Looks like primarily you're missing a `const` in your constructor parameter `val`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e838a31605cdb1f

Comment: _"which is quite efficient"_ Citation needed! I always recommend against nested vectors like this. It's completely unnecessary with a ton of indirection and overhead.

Comment: @ChrisMM Thanks for the answer, I think that solves the question. as an addition to this question, do you know what is vector<int>(2, 0) or TreeNode("str")  in the expression? Is it a temporary object or some kind of constructor?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I just assuming that it doesn't do some value assignment, or manually pushing vectors into vector like `vec.push(vector<int>(15, 0)`. Tought it is efficient. I am wondering about what's the indirection and overhead are like?

Comment: @user542598 Those are both temporaries. Constructing a temporary does involve an invocation of the constructor, yes. Being pedantic, though many people will say that the code is itself a "call to the constructor", it isn't; it just looks like one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string literal like `"abc"` isn't a `std::string`. But that's okay! A `std::string`, such as the one that's a parameter in your `TreeNode` constructor, can be constructed from one automatically.

However, that string will be a *temporary*, and temporaries don't bind to non-`const` references (except with a Visual Studio extension).

That's okay too: you don't need them to; your constructor can take a `const std::string&` instead and everything will be fine.

Other solutions include taking a `std::string` by value, which is actually a good idea as then you can `std::move` from it inside the constructor, and now your constructor is efficient whether you're passing in a temporary or moving in some other named string. But that's a story for another day.

As an aside, if this project is for production, and you are likely to have a lot more vectors than shown in your example, I strongly advise you *don't* nest them like this. Each element has its own memory management and indirection, which is very wasteful. Your data are square (the inner dimension always has the same size), so all you actually need is a single vector of 10*15 `int`s. Then those `int`s will all live in one nice big array, which is cache-friendly and only requires *one* allocation and *one* deallocation! Instead of, like 165, of each. Now you'll have to wrap your accesses in some maths (like `index = y*width + x`) but that's trivial.

Comment: so if we use std::string by value, not reference, does it have the extra copy overhead when we invoke the constructor?

Comment: @user542598 For the call, no, because it'll _move_ from temporaries by default.

Comment: yeah, I know that `std::move()` will not copy the object, but I am thinking that in c++, pass a function parameter by value(not by reference) will trigger a copy? so `TreeNode(std::string value)` will trigger a copy, and `TreeNode(const std::string& value)` will not right? or you are saying that the first one won't trigger a copy even passed by value?

Comment: @user542598 It'll _move_ from temporaries by default. That's how move semantics works!

Answer (score -2):

The problem is not in the initialization of the std::vector (which is correct), but in the initialization of the TreeNode structure.

This altered code works:

```
std::string initVal = "abc";
std::vector<TreeNode> vec(10, TreeNode(initVal));
```

Comment: So source of the problem is?

Comment: That's because VS permits binding temporaries to lvalue refs-to-non-`const`. That's not standard C++.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Doesn't seem like it would be due to the extension since there's an actual variable of the correct type to bind to the reference versus the original temporary.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: works in other compilers too.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ah, I didn't spot that Gabriele is providing fresh code. I'd read the answer as saying the original code worked in VS. My mistake.

Comment: It's still not a great answer though, as it doesn't even attempt to explain _why_ the problem exists and _why_ this changed code fixes it.